# Get possible pairings of elements between 2 sets in python

Tags: python, combinations

For example, I have 10 boys and 10 girls.

In each pairing scenario, I want to pair each boy with one girl. The pairing is exclusive. Once a boy has been paired with a girl, the boy can not be paired with another girl and vice versa.

How can optimally I find all the possible pairing scenarios in python ? Also, how do I describe this problem in proper math terminology.

Thanks!

Edit: add constraint on pairing

Comment: You want to find all the permutations of the two lists?

Comment: What you're describing is the cartesian product of the set of boys and the set of girls.  You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for that.

Comment: @BrenBarn It's not a cartesian product though because the pairing is exclusive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this

```
from itertools import permutations

boys = ['greg', 'john', 'andy']
girls = ['lilly', 'samantha', 'tammy']
pairings = [list(zip(boys, girls_perm)) for girls_perm in permutations(girls)]
```

which gives the possible pairings

```
pairings = 
[[('greg', 'lilly'), ('john', 'samantha'), ('andy', 'tammy')],
 [('greg', 'lilly'), ('john', 'tammy'), ('andy', 'samantha')],
 [('greg', 'samantha'), ('john', 'lilly'), ('andy', 'tammy')],
 [('greg', 'samantha'), ('john', 'tammy'), ('andy', 'lilly')],
 [('greg', 'tammy'), ('john', 'lilly'), ('andy', 'samantha')],
 [('greg', 'tammy'), ('john', 'samantha'), ('andy', 'lilly')]]
```